# How to update a column in a data.frame based on the most frequent entry in R

Tags: r, dataframe

```
mydat <- data.frame(name = c("James", "James", "James", "James", "Leila", "Leila", "Cici", "Bob", "Bob", "Holly", "Topaz", "Topaz"),
                    code = c(123, 928, 981, 333, 981, 928, 463, 123, 928, 981, 333, 444))
> mydat
    name code
1  James  123
2  James  928
3  James  981
4  James  333
5  Leila  981
6  Leila  928
7   Cici  463
8    Bob  123
9    Bob  928
10 Holly  981
11 Topaz  333
12 Topaz  444
```

In `mydat`, each person can have multiple `code`s associated with it. I want to tabulate the `code` column and assign the person the code that is most common.

```
> rbind(table(mydat), Total = colSums(table(mydat)))
      123 333 444 463 928 981
Bob     1   0   0   0   1   0
Cici    0   0   0   1   0   0
Holly   0   0   0   0   0   1
James   1   1   0   0   1   1
Leila   0   0   0   0   1   1
Topaz   0   1   1   0   0   0
Total   2   2   1   1   3   3
```

Bob has `code`s 123 and 928. Since 928 appears more often across `mydat` than 123, Bob will be assigned a `code` of 928.

Cici has `code`  463, so Cici will be assigned a code of 463.

Holly has `code` 981, so Holly will be assigned a code of 981.

James has `code`s 123, 333, 928, and 981. Since 928 and 981 both appear more frequently than 123 and 333, James will be assigned `code`s 928 and 981.

The final output should be:

```
> final_mydat
   name final_code
1   Bob        928
2  Cici        463
3 Holly        981
4 James        928
5 James        981
6 Leila        928
7 Leila        981
8 Topaz        333
```

Is there a quick way to do this in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
mydat %>%
  add_count(code) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  slice_max(n) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 8 × 3
#   name   code     n
#   <chr> <dbl> <int>
# 1 Bob     928     3
# 2 Cici    463     1
# 3 Holly   981     3
# 4 James   928     3
# 5 James   981     3
# 6 Leila   981     3
# 7 Leila   928     3
# 8 Topaz   333     2
```

Add `... %>% select(-n)` if you want to get rid of the `n` column.

Answer (score 2):

In base R we can do

```
by(transform(mydat, score=ave(code, code, FUN=length)), mydat$name, \(x) {
  with(x, x[score == max(score), ])}) |> c(make.row.names=FALSE) |> do.call(what=rbind)
#    name code score
# 1   Bob  928     3
# 2  Cici  463     1
# 3 Holly  981     3
# 4 James  928     3
# 5 James  981     3
# 6 Leila  981     3
# 7 Leila  928     3
# 8 Topaz  333     2
```